# changing the clicked image in the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

i am making this simple canvas . it has three images in it (identical images). i want to change only the clicked image. what i am trying to do is save the image order in a array . and  only the change the index of the image which was clicked .
so far i am clueless how to do so ! i have done it with hard coded but cnt do this in general as i dnt know where the user clicked . if i could get the position of the mouse when it was clicked or the id of the image which was clicked i could do something but i am new in html5 so i have no idea how to do so , can any one point me in the right direction ? here is my code

```
    <style> 
        body {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }

        #myCanvas {
            border: 2px solid #9C9898;
        }
    </style> 
    <script> 

       if(window.addEventListener) {

window.addEventListener('load', function ()
{

           var my = new Array();
var i=0;
            var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            var imageObj = new Image();
            var imageObj1 = new Image();
            imageObj.onload = function(){
 imageObj1.src = "watermelon-duck-outline.png";
 for (var x = 0; x <= 1200;x += 400 ) { alert(i,x);
  my[i]=imageObj;
 context.drawImage(imageObj, x, 0);
++i;
}
context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
            }
            imageObj.src = "tomato2.jpg";

            change.addEventListener('mousedown', function ()      {ButtonDown (change)}, false);

            function ButtonDown (change)
{ canvas.width = canvas.width; 
 i--;
 for (var x = 800; x >= 0;x -= 400 ) {
  if(i!=2){my[i]=imageObj;}else{my[i]=imageObj1;}
 context.drawImage(my[i], x, 0);
i--;
}}



         init();
}, false); }
    </script> 
</head> 
<body >

    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1250" height="650"> 
    </canvas>
    <button id="change" type="button">Change</button>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/YE5Rs/1/)**

This is how I would do it. Basically you need to store the `x,y,width,height` of each image. You need these values so that when you click within the canvas you can check the bounds of each image against the x and y of the mouse click. After that its easy to reference which image was clicked. Hopefully the following code is enough to get you on the right track.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = "#f00";
ctx.strokeStyle = "#0f0";

var images = [];
images.push({x : 10, y : 10, width:50, height:50}, {x : 70, y : 10, width:50, height:50}, {x : 130, y : 10, width:50, height:50});

//draw some rects, this would be your images
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
    ctx.fillRect(images[i].x, images[i].y, images[i].width, images[i].height); 
}

canvas.onclick = function(e){
    var x = 0,
        y = 0;

    if (e.pageX || e.pageY) { 
        x = e.pageX;
        y = e.pageY;
    }
    else { 
        x = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft; 
        y = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop; 
    } 

    x -= canvas.offsetLeft;
    y -= canvas.offsetTop;

// This is where you go through all the images, and check the x and y from the mouse event against your images.
    for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
        if(x > images[i].x && x < images[i].x + images[i].width && y > images[i].y && y < images[i].y + images[i].height){
            ctx.strokeRect(images[i].x, images[i].y, images[i].width, images[i].height); 
          alert('Image ' + i + ' selected');  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wht is (e) ? i am sorry for sounding dum , but i am new at html5

Comment: `e` is just the event object for the click event, it has the values available like the `x` and `y` where the user clicked.

Comment: so what will be the function defination ? function ButtonDown (e) ?? because i want to do this function when button is clicked

Comment: Hmm I guess I am confused. You will *have* to have a click event in order to get what image the user clicked on. What is the change button supposed to do? Redraw the images in a different order?

Comment: actually i have multiple images to replace the selected image , so the button down chooses the image . but with this function i want the x,y co ordinates of the clicked image. so i can tell which image was clicked . kindly help in function definition and how to call it ?