# HTML5 Canvas, how to auto update image after changing img source with Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

http://shedlimited.debrucellc.com/

I'm using an html canvas with clipping region etc in the center to draw images, drag, and resize;

On the right I'm using PHP/Ajax to offer users the ability to upload a new image.

After the new image is uploaded, I use jQuery to change the img.src of the image being displayed on the canvas (I'm pulling this data from a text file I wrote to in PHP script fyi which I can't get to work with variables etc).

The process is

1) upload new image,

2) click on the pillow to change the image src, using following code:

```
$('.button2').click(function()
    {   
jQuery.get('scripts/testFile.txt', function(data) {
sourcer = data;
    });
```

3) the image won't change automatically on the canvas, so I have to click on the image on the canvas for the new image source to be updated, and than the image changes to the new img.src

My QUESTION: I want to remove this step 3) so that the user doesn't have to click on the image to change it, and all they have to do is complete step 2) -> click on the button to change the image,

So could I somehow simulate the image being clicked from jquery?

Comment: Simple fix is a manual call `click` after updating `source` like this `$("img id").click()`

Comment: @DON but the image doesn't have an ID its just 'img' etc because it is HTML5 unless I'm mistaken? Have you tested this?

Comment: I seen the link, you may try this `$("#container2 canvas").click()`

Comment: @DON thx but doesn't work

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391974/changing-the-clicked-image-in-the-canvas